# IIS Mail from Pickup directory not going into Badmail folder

Tags: iis, smtp

I have been testing my SMTP setup on IIS6 today. I have created a test.eml file that I palce in my pickup directory and it gets sent out. However, when I put a bad address into the file it is not going into the badmail folder. The file disappears and it seems to be removed from the file system.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be CW, and belongs on SF

Comment: Huh? I don't understand...

Comment: I've seen this issue, but wasn't able to resolve it

Comment: From the help:"Badmail directory:  When a message is undeliverable, it is returned to the sender with a non-delivery report (NDR). You can designate that copies of the NDR are sent to a location of your choice. All NDRs go through the same delivery process as other messages, including attempts to resend the message. If the NDR has reached the retry limit and cannot be delivered to the sender, a copy of the message is placed in the Badmail directory."  Is the message meeting these configurable conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange 2003 SP1 Microsoft made changes to the badmail folder that effectively disabled it due to the fact that it would fill up, unbeknownst to the sysadmin, until all available drive space was consumed. I don't know if there was a complementary change to IIS but you can check for the existence of the following registry key value:

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SMTPSVC\Queuing|MaxBadMailFolderSize

If it exists and the setting is 0, then badmail queueing is disabled and all message that wind up there are automatically deleted.